# How can I hide extra divs with an ellipsis?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, ellipsis

I have a tag input field and I need to show just as many as will fit into the fake "input" div surrounding it, like this:

```
<div class="btn btn-secondary">
  <span class="tag">Tag 1</span>
  <span class="tag">Tag 2</span>
  <span class="tag">Tag 3</span>
  <span class="tag">Tag 4</span>
  <input>
</div>
```

(I add tags programatically there, an Angular component). My outer div with the button class is pretending to be an input, and inside I show current tags (styled) and the actual input to the right of them.
The goal is to show a few tags, as much as will fit, and then leave a bit of space for the input, like this:

```
________________________________
| tag1  tag2  tag3  ... _INPUT_ |
---------------------------------
```

The tags are styled (and with an X button). So if I remove a few tags, I need to remove the ellipsis (**...**) and if I add more, they are not to be shown (they're in a tooltip).

The input has a minimum width, but it should fill up space if there aren't any (or enough) tags. So, `tag tag inpuuuuuuuuuuuuut` all the way to the right border. And if we remove one tag, the input fills up the space, if we add one, input shrinks (up until minWidth).

What would be a common-sense way to doing this? I am thinking that I would need to have each tag calculate and report it's width, then have that wrapper div pick how ever many will fit and hide the others, and add the ellipsis tag if needed. Is there a simpler way (IE11 minimum support needed)?

Comment: This will require JavaScript, not CSS. There is no support in CSS or HTML for showing ellipses for an overflowing *count of elements*, only for text.

Comment: @TylerH I know it will, I just forgot the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a *crazy* idea using some flex and positionning *(you may have to adjust some values depending on your situation)*

```css
.btn {
  width: 310px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
  width: 170px;
}

.btn > div {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn > div > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn > div > div:after {
  content: "...";
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.tag {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span class="tag">Tag 1</span>
      <span class="tag">Tag 2</span>
      <span class="tag">Tag 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span class="tag">Tag 1</span>
      <span class="tag">Tag 2</span>
      <span class="tag">Tag 3</span>
      <span class="tag">Tag 4</span>
      <span class="tag">Tag 5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span class="tag">Tag 1</span>
      <span class="tag">Tag 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span class="tag">Tag 1</span>
      <span class="tag">Tag 2</span>
      <span class="tag">Tag 3</span>
      <span class="tag">Tag 4</span>
      <span class="tag">Tag 5</span>
      <span class="tag">Tag 6</span>
      <span class="tag">Tag 7</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Now the input will stretch to the left in case there is no enough tags:

```css
.btn {
  width: 310px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 170px;
}

.btn > div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn > div:after {
  content: "...";
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.tag {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <div>
    <span class="tag">Tag 1</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 2</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 3</span>
  </div>
  <input>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <div>
    <span class="tag">Tag 1</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 2</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 3</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 4</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 5</span>
  </div>
  <input>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <div>
    <span class="tag">Tag 1</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 2</span>
  </div>
  <input>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <div>
    <span class="tag">Tag 1</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 2</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 3</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 4</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 5</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 6</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 7</span>
  </div>
  <input>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <div>
    <span class="tag">Tag 1</span>
  </div>
  <input>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <div>
  </div>
  <input>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any "..." in the snippet preview. :(

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas which browser ?

Comment: Chrome 63 on Windows 10 Pro. With your latest edit now I've got ellipses in the 2nd and 4th examples. :)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes the input has a default width which is not the same everywhere, so i change it :) by the way it remain a crazy idea and need some hardcoded value ;)

Comment: This looks quite good :) If I can understand what you did and adjust it to my code :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have one more requirement, then I can vote promoting you into CSS god :)  Anyway: is there a way to make that input fill content to the left when there aren't as many tags? It should have min-width, but max width is the surounding box.

Comment: @Zlatko ok so, if no tag it should take all the width then ?

Comment: @Zlatko i added an update, le me know if this what you want or not :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="btn btn-secondary">
  <div class="tag-box">
    <span class="tag">Tag 1</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 223131</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 31231</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 4</span>
    <span class="tag">Tag 5</span>
  </div>
  <input>
</div>

.tag-box {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid;
    max-width: 140px;
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.tag-box .tag {
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dm7bmzky/34/

Comment: Can you make your answer more code-specific? Use the `code tags` available from stackoverflow and structure your answer. Maybe even give an example?

Comment: posted the solution

Comment: @StaverVasile thanks, but how would this be dynamic? What if the fourth tag does not fit, and I have to put ellipsis after the third tag? And then adding the ellipsis, it would become too wide again so I have to actually place it behind the second tag?