# CSS related to overflow - What is analogous to text-overflow for html elements?

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div className="abcd">
<span>
<span className="abc"></span><span className="abc"></span><span className="abc"></span><span className="abc"></span><span className="abc"></span><span className="abc"></span>
</span>
</div>
```

If i set a max height for the div, similar to text-overlfow: 'ellipsis', how can i show some span elements and then show ellipsis alongside it.

```
span {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;

        }
```

This  does not work. Within the div i would like ellipsis to appear when max-height is reached. This works fine for `<p className"para">blahblahblah</p>` So if we set get something like blahblah...

I want a similar result.

Comment: Could you please provide css as well for classes abc, abc1, abc2 and abc3

Comment: the short answer is you cannot ... here is a similar question to get some idea of workaround : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868798/how-can-i-hide-extra-divs-with-an-ellipsis/48869062#48869062

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from [How can I hide extra divs with an ellipsis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868798/how-can-i-hide-extra-divs-with-an-ellipsis/48869062#48869062)

```
.abcd {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid;
    max-width: 140px;
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.abcd .abc {
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webkit based browsers, you can use  -webkit-line-clamp

```
overflow: hidden;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vRYedp

Reference - [Is vertical text-overflow possible with css3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004006/is-vertical-text-overflow-possible-with-css3) and
https://medium.com/mofed/css-line-clamp-the-good-the-bad-and-the-straight-up-broken-865413f16e5

Use options provided in below question for all browsers without using -webkit-line-clamp

[Clamping lines without '-webkit-line-clamp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763551/clamping-lines-without-webkit-line-clamp)